# how to set crossdomain in ionic angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

how to set the below angular 1 settings in angular 2?

```
 $.ajax({
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,
                    type: "get",
                    url: _1 + 'cbsonlineusers.php?jsoncallback=?',
                    data: MemStat,
                    dataType: "json",
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple plugin for chrome [from this link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)